# Nginx reverse proxy to ip address with a same domain name

Tags: networking, dns, proxy, nginx, reverse-proxy

Let's say, I have DEV, TEST, QA and PRODUCTION servers for 'custom.domain.com'. In public, DNS servers probably have CNAME(or A Record) to PRODUCTION servers.

In my local box, I want to run E2E tests with Nginx reverse proxy, which allows us to access DEV(or Test, QA) in 'custom.domain.com'(I don't want to change hosts file). Given that TEST server ip address is 10.0.29.1, what would be correct Nginx configuration roughly?

Comment: You can `proxy_pass` to an IP address and use `proxy_set_header Host` to select the correct `server` block on the test machine.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So, the configuration below may work?

proxy_pass http://10.0.29.1;
proxy_set_header Host custom.domain.com;